# Using Docker Windows containers on air-gapped machines

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

I want to use Docker to manage software on some air-gapped servers running Windows 10 Enterprise, but I can't find any clear info on whether what I want to do is allowed by Microsoft's licensing of it's containers. I want to keep the base Windows images in a private registry so that I can easily spin up new machines, but I can't find any clear info on the actual restrictions on all the official Microsoft Windows base layers. I know that the images are non-redistributable, but it's unclear as to what this actually means. I don't have plans for other employees using these images, but I have considered that Docker may be useful in improving some of our workflow, assuming that it's allowed. Can I place these base images into a private, air-gapped registry for use by my servers and other employees? Or do I need to have an internet connection to use them?

Also, I want to use Docker to containerize our tools and compile binaries on build servers, some of which would be used as a released binary for our products, does this fall under the restriction Microsoft places on using their images for production purposes? These images would not be used to host external facing web applications, simply compiling code and packaging the output so that it can be tested and eventually be released.